# Thinkpad X200t Volume mute button not recognised to use as shurtcut

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 on my Thinkpad X200t. However, my volume mute button does not work whilst volume up and down buttons work flawlessly.

I tried to edit the shortcut key that is assigned to `Volume mute` in the keyboard settings [1] but the button is not recognised.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjTKK.jpg

What else can I try?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a X200 and faced the same Problem. The reason for this malfunction is explained [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Mute_button).

I finally made the mute-button work by installing a patched kernel-version. It's quite easy; just add the PPA given [here](http://thinkwiki.de/Ubuntu_ThinkPad_Extras_PPA) and update your system. That should to the trick.